# Lightning component's .focus() not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have an input field:

`<ui:inputText aura:id="name-input"/>`

With controller code:

```
var input = cmp.find("name-input");
console.log(input);    
input.focus();
```

This gives the error:

> Access Check Failed! Component.method():'markup://ui:focus' is not visible to 'markup://c:TimeTagCreator {100:0}'.

I can even see that the `.focus()` method exists, with the output of that `console.log();` being:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: have you tried this?

    var input = cmp.find("name-input").getElement();
    input.focus();

Comment: `getElement()` isn't defined on lightning components when LockerService is enabled. That would would on an `<input>`, but doesn't on a `<ui:inputText>`

Comment: One small but important detail to note here is that `getElement()` *is* defined on lightning components with LockerService enabled for components that you own. So if you built a <c:foo> component, for example, that had a single `<input>` element inside, `getElement()` would in fact return that input. It doesn't work in the OP case because the `<input>` lives inside `ui:inputText`, which would only be accessible to `ui` components, not your custom namespace.

Comment: @TrevorBliss I'm not sure that is correct, as I can't see this method even in the situation you are describing

Comment: @nicstella `focus()` is an `aura:method` defined on the `ui:inputText` so if you are expected `focus()` to be visible in the situation I describe with the custom built <c:foo> component, you need to explicitly define that aura:method yourself. I was just using the custom component as an example for how `getElement()` works.

Answer (score 11):

You're getting an Access Check Failure (ACF) here because the `focus` aura:method on `ui:input` (which `ui:inputText` extends) is not marked `access=GLOBAL` so it is not public available for use. Even though you can see the method defined on the `ui:inputText` object, the framework will verify access before letting you call it.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/input/input.cmp#L69

You can see more info on ACFs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_intro.htm#access_intro

Since it's still in Beta, don't use it for anything that will end up in a managed package, but have you tried out `lightning:input`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

Of course, you can always roll your own using the native `<input>` tag, but I do think this is something that should be fixed by the framework.

**Edit**:

The `focus()` method of lightning:input also throws an ACF currently, but will be fixed in the Spring '17 major release.

Comment: I would strongly not recommend to use BETA tags if the app is to released as managed package .BETA components cannot be packaged and unless the component is GA i would be hesitant to try BETA for managed package builds

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes good point. I updated my answer to include that disclaimer.

Comment: A viable option, except it forces you into the slds styling by default and _requires_ a label, which is awkward if you want to do your own things with it

Comment: Just tried it; despite explicitly starting that `.focus()` is supported, I still get an `Access Check Failed!` error

Comment: @nicstella Interesting, this is working for me. Could you share what your markup and javascript looks like? I have a `<lightning:input aura:id="input" name="quantity" value="1234567890" label="Quantity" />` in markup and then in a button click handler `component.find("input").focus()`. I see the focus changing to the input and no ACFs in the console.

Comment: Very interesting: I literally just copy/paste your code and it won't work for me. I am totally confused now

Comment: @nicstella You're right. The ACF is still on the current code line but is fixed for the Spring '17 major release. Apologies, I was on a more current code line.

Comment: @TrevorBliss - I want to use base `<lightning:buttonMenu />` component in a managed package, but you mentioned not to use it in managed apps because they are in `Beta`. I'm unable to find any warning references to this in documentation. Can you confirm what will happen if we do package with Beta Base Component in our components?

Comment: @VarunC I'm no expert on the subject, but I've been told there is no physical limitation to using Beta components in managed packages. Since they are in Beta, however, they may be less reliable as they haven't had as much time to hash out any potential bugs.

Comment: that's what i was thinking, just got concerned about the physical limitation that i didn't knew about. Thanks for clearing that up :-)

Comment: Wondering if the same fix is in progress for lightning:inputRichText? I realize it's beta but it's recommended for Summer 17 per the doc on ui:inputRichText but I can't seem to set focus to it. Just need to be able to inform the client and I doubt I'll be able to access the underlying quill api to force it myself without getting smacked aroud ACF wise.. thanks!

Comment: I'm not the best person to ask for that but since it's documented I assume it'll be available by the time it's not BETA if it isn't already available. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputRichText.htm

Answer (score 6):

`aura:id` allow you to use focus:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="name-input"/>
```

Then, when the modal is displayed, select your input in your javascript function, and set the focus to it:

```
component.find("name-input").getElement().focus();
```

> Make sure `<ui:inputText aura:id="name-input"/>` rendered propery.
>   If still not working try to add setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    component.find("name-input").getElement().focus();
}, 100);
```

Comment: getElement() is not working in a winter 18 dev box. I think it is yet to be fixed as mentioned in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this, I used the similar code for my desktop LEX, it works,
But it not working on the mobile (Salesforce App pages).

<ui:inputText id="{!globalId}" aura:id="name-input"/> 

var el = 
document.getElementById(component.getGlobalId('name-input'));
el.focus();
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why your code should work just dumping code anda sking for the OP to try it is not relaly usefull for anyone reading it, take a moment to re-read [answer] if you havent done so already. Thanks

Comment: This won't work because ui:inputText doesn't support id attribute.

Comment: Every component has a unique globalId, which is the generated runtime-unique ID of the component instance.  The idea is getting the unique id of this HTML element, then focus on it. It works for my project, one exception is Safari browser-based app. I resolved it by using ui:scrollerWrapper (Github source code of Aura project explains why scrollerWrapper works in Safari).